# Trying to aggregate string column by choosing 1 of several values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset that I want to aggregate based on a string column.  Dataset is basically:

```
system      status
-------------------
PRE1-SYS1   SUCCESS
PRE1-SYS2   SUCCESS
PRE2-SYS1   RUNNING
PRE2-SYS2   SUCCESS
PRE3-SYS1   SUCCESS
PRE3-SYS2   <blank>
```

Basically, I want this to become:

```
system      status
-------------------
PRE1    SUCCESS
PRE2    RUNNING
PRE3    RUNNING
```

I have the sql needed to trim down the system values to PRE1, and PRE2, but I'm not sure how to aggregate the string function so that a system is:

- only SUCCESS, then status is SUCCESS
- only nulls, then status is PENDING
- any other combination, then RUNNING (SUCCESS/RUNNING, SUCCESS/null, RUNNING/null)

I've looked at LISTAGG but I don't think it applies.

Comment: The requirement is still unclear. "or, if and only, then PENDING" has no meaning in English, what were you trying to say? Do you mean if there is at least one `null` then status is PENDING? What if you have a row with RUNNING and another with `null` - is that PENDING or RUNNING? Note that LISTAGG has nothing to do with this.

Comment: supposed to say blank but I used angle brackets so it HTML'd me.  fixing.

Comment: Thank you for editing. PRE3 shows SUCCESS and `null` but the result is PENDING, but in words you said "if ONLY NULL" then PENDING. Which is it?

Comment: if it's not all success and not all blank, it should be running. will fix.

Comment: After update: PRE3 does not have only nulls, yet you choose PENDING. Why?

Comment: if one part of a system has succeeded but another is null(pending), then it can be assumed that system is actually running but the second part hasn't started yet.

Comment: But your rules (#2) say it should be pending only when all are null. Your question is inconsistent.

Comment: I see it now, I fixed the target output section, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an SQL query you could use:

```
select   regexp_substr(system, '^[^-]*') as prefix,
         case
            when count(status) = 0 then 'PENDING'
            when count(*) = count(case when status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end) then 'SUCCESS'
            else 'RUNNING'
         end as status
from     mytable
group by regexp_substr(system, '^[^-]*')
```

Comment: thank you, this worked well.  Apologies for the confusion in the target output in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

```
with
     inputs ( system, status ) as (
       select 'PRE1-SYS1', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE1-SYS2', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE2-SYS1', 'RUNNING' from dual union all
       select 'PRE2-SYS2', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE3-SYS1', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE3-SYS2',  ''       from dual
     ),
     prep ( system, flag ) as (
       select substr(system, 1, instr(system, '-') - 1),
              case status when 'SUCCESS' then 0 
                          when 'RUNNING' then 1 else 2 end
       from   inputs
     )
select system,
       case when min(flag) = 2 then 'PENDING'
            when max(flag) = 0 then 'SUCCESS'
            else                    'RUNNING' end as status
from prep
group by system
order by system;
```

**Output**:

```
SYSTEM    STATUS
--------- -------
PRE1      SUCCESS
PRE2      RUNNING
PRE3      RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it by ranking the responses.  For example set a value to the most desired to the least desired results:

```
SUCCESS = 1
RUNNING = 2
<blank> = 3
PENDING = 3
```

Then select a min based on that.

```
select xval = case status when 'Success' then 1
                          when 'Running' then 2
                          when 'Pending' then 3
                                         else 3
                          end
```

Use a nested sub select on the value you get here so you only get one record per system.
    select System, Min(Xval)

```
then display the 1 as Success
             the 2 as Running
             and 3 as Pending
```

It is hard to do in text format, easier to do with numbers.  The numbers you assign to the string are important because they determine when you have multiple values which single one you return in your final query.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.  Practically, this ends up being very similar to @trincot's solution, I'm just separating the logic for getting the counts from the logic that interprets those counts.  If your logic gets more complicated in the future, this may be a bit more flexible.

```
with
     inputs ( system, status ) as (
       select 'PRE1-SYS1', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE1-SYS2', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE2-SYS1', 'RUNNING' from dual union all
       select 'PRE2-SYS2', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE3-SYS1', 'SUCCESS' from dual union all
       select 'PRE3-SYS2',  ''       from dual
     ),
     /* The cnts CTE counts how many rows relate to a SYSTEM, 
        how many of those are SUCCESS, and how many are NULL.
      */
     cnts( system, num_rows, num_success, num_null ) as (
       select substr(system,1,instr(system, '-')-1) system,
              count(*),
              sum(case when status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end),
              sum(case when status is null then 1 else 0 end)
        from inputs
       group by substr(system,1,instr(system, '-')-1)
     )
/* Using the counts from the CTE, we can implement whatever logic we
   want
 */
select system,
       (case when num_rows = num_success then 'SUCCESS'
             when num_rows = num_null then 'PENDING'
             else 'RUNNING'
         end) status
  from cnts
```